# StackBlitz Can't Locate Existing Angular SCSS File

Tags: angular, angular7, stackblitz

I am moving an app to Angular 7 app StackBlitz that was developed in VSCode. The angular.json has been adjusted to work with SCSS. Other SCSS files seem to be found successfully. But StackBlitz is complaining that it cannot find a file that is in the exact path of the error message. Please advise.  I've attached a graphic.[image]

Comment: Actually the error is *inside* the `account.component.scss` file. It's probably the `@import "../../../variables.scss";` line, as the file is actually called `_variables.scss` from the looks of it. (Bear in mind there seem to be a few files with the same issue)

Comment: Yes, the error moves from file to file. It is working fine in VSCode. Normally scss ignores the underscore.  But sure enough adding the underscore made the difference in StackBlitz.  Thanks